# Recycler View is not scrolling in Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I have created a navigation drawer and in the main content of navigation drawer I have a RecyclerView but it's not scrolling. Initially I have put RecyclerView without NestedScrollView  but that didn't work, so I tried putting it inside NestedScrollView but the latter didn't work also.

My navigation drawer XML is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.roushan.assignment1.NavDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/nav_toolbar_color"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT OF NAVIGATION DRAWER ACTIVITY -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer_drawer" >


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The main content goes inside the `<DrawerLayout>`, before the `<NavigationView>`. Also, you don't need the `NestedScrollView`, necessarily.

Comment: That's  worked .. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: No problem. Please do [accept the answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if it solved your problem, by ticking the checkmark under the arrows. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As Mike pointed out , the way you have structured the layout is wrong. Please modify the layout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.roushan.assignment1.NavDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/nav_toolbar_color"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer_drawer" >
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```